# background color phantomjs

Tags: css, phantomjs

The background color for a div or any kind of element is skipped by phantomjs. By default it's set in the CSS but I tried as well to set it with Javascript or as style parameters in the balise but nothing work out. I don't get any background color.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: have you tried !important flag for background in your css?

Comment: @Pavel !important doesn't change anything

Comment: I am using bootsrap, if I remove all the section @media print { in the css, I get the wished result. How can I say to phantomjs to don't use this print view?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was coming from the bootsrap CSS (media print) and the fact that phantomjs use the print mode. In order to solve the problem, I commented out the line "@import print.less;" in bootsrap.less. This solution work only if you are using less with boostrap.